# How to force OctoberCMS to use relative URLs instead of absolute?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

I can link assets manually with relative URL by forgoing `|theme` filter, however plugins still use absolute path, which creates issues when I share and test my project. Is there a native way to make October use relative urls?

Comment: The AssetMaker always returns absolute URLs ( https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/system/traits/AssetMaker.php#L271 ). If you really need this, the only way I can think of is registering a middleware and modify the response to rewrite any absolute URLs. This however does not sound very performant and will probably be error prone. What is the exact issue you are having using the absolute paths?

Comment: Sharing my local environment with clients and colleagues suing ngrok.io, it expects relative path to load website css, js, and etc. So plugin scripts won't load up.

Comment: I think the way to go is a middleware then.

Answer (score 0):

You can have assets in your plugin folder. Then in your component's onRun function, load them.

```
public function onRun()
    {
        $this->addCss('/plugins/cleanse/pvpactions/assets/css/actions.css');
        $this->addJs('/plugins/cleanse/pvpactions/assets/js/axios.min.js');
    }
```

http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#component-assets